# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i dont know how to solve this problem

here is my controller

```
 public function actionView($id)
  {
    $view = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['blog.id', 'user_id', 'body', 'title'])
        ->from('blog')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'users', 'blog.user_id = users.id')
        ->where(['blog.id' => $id])
        ->one();

    return $this->render('view', compact('view','id'));
  }
```

here is my view

```
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2><?= $view['name'] . ' ' . $view['surname'] ?></h2>
            <h3><?= $view['title']; ?></h3>
            <p><?= $view['body']; ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo yii::$app->homeUrl; ?>" class="btn btn-default">Back </a>
            <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $view['id']], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked what `$view` is in the controller?

Comment: now i did it but i get nothing. i think i have to check my query again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use checks if the specific key exists in your `$view` data.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2><?= ($view['name'] ?? '') . ' ' . ($view['surname'] ?? '') ?></h2>
    <h3><?= $view['title'] ?? ''; ?></h3>
    <p><?= $view['body'] ?? ''; ?></p>

    <a href="<?= Yii::$app->homeUrl; ?>" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>

    <?php
        if ($view) {
            echo Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $view['id']], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])
        } 
    ?>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

You can basically check if you fetch `$view` data in your controller also and respond to user if criteria conditions did not match any record from the database:

```
 public function actionView($id) 
 {
    $view = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['blog.id', 'user_id', 'body', 'title'])
            ->from('blog')
            ->join('INNER JOIN', 'users', 'blog.user_id = users.id')
            ->where(['blog.user_id' => $id])
            ->one();

    if (!empty($view)) {
        return $this->render('view', compact('view','id'));
    }

    throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('The requested blog does not exist.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.your method solved my problem.now i have to check my controller becouse i fetch zero data from DB

Comment: Yes, according to my answer in your view file, if you do not fetch `$view` data by criteria in your controller, it will output blank page details with `Back` button only. I would suggest you also to check in controller, something like this: `if (empty($view)) { // 404 Not Found Exception  } else { // render your view with data }`

Comment: public function actionView($id)
    {
        $view = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['blog.id', 'user_id', 'body', 'title'])
            ->from('blog')
            ->join('INNER JOIN', 'users', 'blog.user_id = users.id')
            ->where(['blog.user_id' => $id])
            ->one();
        if (empty($view))
        {
            echo 'no data';
        }else {
            return $this->render('view', compact('view','id'));
        }

        return $this->render('view', compact('view','id'));

    }

Comment: You can use `exceptions` rather than `echo` the response.

Comment: Thanks you very much. my all problems is solved. <3. i always worked in Laravel. but now im working for another company and here have only one project with yii2. i started learning this framework 5 days ago.when i start work with Laravel i forgot core php )

Comment: I am glad to hear that I have helped you.